# Generate ef6 sql update script from code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

When I run `update-database -Script` from the Nuget Package Manager Console, Visual studio generates a SQL script which I can run to update the database.

Is there any way to generate this SQL script in C# without running it?

That way I can show it to the user who is updating the application before updating the database.

Comment: Try `update-database -Verbose`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DbMigrator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigrator(v=vs.113).aspx) and [MigratorScriptingDecorator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.infrastructure.migratorscriptingdecorator(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
var configuration = new DbMigrationsConfiguration
{
    ContextType = typeof(ApplicationDbContext),
    MigrationsAssembly = typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly,
    MigrationsNamespace = "YourNamespace.Migrations",
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true
};
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
var migratorScriptingDecorator = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(dbMigrator);
string script = migratorScriptingDecorator.ScriptUpdate(sourceMigration: null, targetMigration: null);
```